# jQuery - hide an element inside bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to hide a button (assume this as buttonA) inside a bootstrap modal popup. Here I have buttonB and buttonC at different places and both are used to trigger the same popup but my problem is I have to hide buttonA when popup is triggered from buttonB and show it when triggered from buttonC.

I tried the below generic code in jQuery but it is not working for me, is there any way to make this happen while using bootstrap modal popup.

```js
$('#buttonB').click(function() {
  alert('test');
  $('#buttonA').hide();
});
```

Comment: Is the alert firing?

Comment: No it is not firing alert, I have loaded jquery and bootstrap correctly, also no console errors.

Comment: Is '#buttonB' a dynamically added element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `#buttonB` is a dynamically created element then use jQuery's [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function in the following format: `$(staticAncestors).on(eventName, dynamicChild, function() {});`

StaticAncestors would be the closest parent element that is static.

```
$(staticAncestors).on('click', '#buttonB', function() {
  alert('test');
  $('#buttonA').hide();
});
```